# callrail api secondary request parameters

Tags: get

How do I add secondary request parameters using callrail api?

Independently the following two work.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token={faketoken123}" \
-X GET \
"https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{accountId123}/calls.json?fields=first_time_callers,leads"
```

gets back the fields I need.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token={faketoken123}" \
-X GET \
"https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{accountId123}/calls.json?company_id={companyId123}"
```

gets back specified company.

I need to combine the two. Here is what I've attempted:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token={faketoken123}" \
-X GET \
"https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{accountId123}/calls.json?company_id={companyId123}&fields=first_time_callers,leads"
```

I've looked through all their [documentation](http://apidocs.callrail.com/#summarizing-call-data) . Without figuring out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3/31/2017 CallRail API does not currently accept secondary parameters in the HTTP request.

I received an e-mail from their support team telling me they are working on supporting that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can add secondary request parameters.

```
 var myToken = "4b20c9154e1b21ca5fc30b5c5725729a";
 var accountId = "356-678-890";
 var companyId = "756789417";
 var startDate = "2017-07-03";
 var endDate = "2017-08-05";

$.ajax
     ({
       type: "GET",
       url: "https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/" + accountId + "/calls.json?fields=tags,lead_status&company_id=" + companyId + "&start_date=" + startDate + "&end_date=" + endDate,
       dataType: 'json',
       headers: {"Authorization": 'Token token=' + myToken},
       success: function (result) {
               // your code
       },
     });
```